# Implement AMP in the laravel 5.6 on dynamic old pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, amp-html

I am working on a laravel 5.6 and now I want to implement AMP pages

All the pages are dynamic which are coming from MySQL, now I want to make those pages into AMP what is the best practice? I understand laravel and AMP very well.

What I figure out is, in the URL add an extra parameter as example.com/someurl/amp and normal page example.com/someurl
but on the fly How to convert normal HTML tags to AMP tags.

I am really sorry for the bad English and thank you in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be not to use dynamic content on AMP pages.